# How to convince python tox to run tests only for the available python interpreters?

Tags: python, tox

I am using python [tox](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/tox) to run python unittest for several versions of python, but these python interpreters are not all available on all machines or platforms where I'm running tox.

How can I configure tox so it will run tests only when python interpretors are available.

Example of `tox.ini`:

```
[tox]
envlist=py25,py27

[testenv]
...
[testenv:py25]
...
```

The big problem is that I do want to have a list of python environments which is auto-detected.

Comment: Doesn't it already do that? I recall that is detects missing interpreters and skips the associated tests (quite quickly too).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of Tox version 1.7.2, you can pass the `--skip-missing-interpreters` flag to achieve this behavior. You can also set `skip_missing_interpreters=true` in your `tox.ini` file. More info [here](http://tox.readthedocs.org/en/latest/config.html#confval-skip_missing_interpreters=BOOL).

```
[tox]
envlist =
    py24, py25, py26, py27, py30, py31, py32, py33, py34, jython, pypy, pypy3
skip_missing_interpreters =
    true
```

Answer (score 0):

First if you don't have tox : `pip install tox`.

Use this command : `tox --skip-missing-interpreters` , it skips for the compilers which are not available locally and just runs for the available versions of python

Answer (score -3):

tox will display an Error if an interpreter cannot be found.   Question is up if there should be a "SKIPPED" state and making tox return a "0" success result. This should probably be explicitely enabled via a command line option. If you agree, file an issue at http://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox .

Comment: I added a feature request https://bitbucket.org/hpk42/tox/issue/59/allow-tox-to-ignore-missing-python Tx

Comment: You could recommend usage of SO for most tox/pytest relates questions - as main support option. It's much better than any mailinglist. Still, mailing list has it's use.

Comment: i think i am already recommending it, at least for pytest.  Only caveat is that answers that were good 3 years ago might not be good/valid anymore now.

Comment: I can only hope that SO will change the policy regarding accepted answers, the pressure is building so it will happen eventually.